# How to modify this Python define function code?

Tags: python, function, iterable

Could anyone please take a look at the following function code in Python?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import poisson, norm

cs = 100
co = 300
mu = 4.7

G = poisson(mu)
p = G.pmf(np.arange(3*mu))

# Define Z(Q) function 

def Z(Q):
    for i in range(len(p)):
        return sum(p[i]*cs*max((Q-i), 0) + p[i]*co*max((i-Q), 0))

# Plot Q and (Q)

import pylab as pl

x = []
y = []

for Q in range(0, 12):
    x.append(Q)
    y.append(Z(Q))

pl.plot(x, y, '-o')
pl.show()
```

Error Message shows up in the last 'Plot' procedure: 
In Z(Q), 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable.

I would like Z(Q) returns value that sum each i in the range (0, len(p)), which is a function with variable Q. And finally the plot is Q(X Axis) and Z(Q)(Y Axis) for each Q it can be plotted.

How can I modify Z(Q)? Thank you!

And if I would like to output [Q, Z(Q)] how could I make it? My Code:

```
   with open('opt.csv', 'wb') as fd:
        a = csv.writer(fd, delimiter=',')
        data1 = [['Order_Number', 'Cost'],
                 [Q, Z(Q)]]
        a.writerows(data1)
```

Comment: Please give us the *full, exact error message and trace.*

Comment: Hint: consider a function f containing the lines `def f():` and `<tab>for i in range(10):` and `<tab><tab>return i`. What do you expect `print(f())` to display? The result may surprise you.

Comment: @deceze Question edited, thanks!

Comment: @Kevin My f() would like to return a function only has variable Q, so that for each i within the range, summarize them and get a f(Q)

Comment: @Kevin Right, as you said if I tried the hint from you, it has error: name 'i' is not defined.

Comment: The code I described shouldn't give a NameError. It should print "0". The purpose of the exercise was to demonstrate that a `return` in a loop will only return once, giving you `0` instead of, say, `[0,1,2,3... 9]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're expecting Z(Q) to return multiple values, you may want to use the "yield" statement:

```
def Z(Q):
    for i in range(len(p)):
        yield sum(p[i]*cs*max((Q-i), 0) + p[i]*co*max((i-Q), 0))
```

This will allow it to be iterated over and will return the sum for each run of the for loop.

If you need the ouput as a list rather than a generic iterable, you'll either need to construct the list in that call, or wrap your call to Z(Q) in a list: list(Z(Q))

---

**Edit:**

After taking a closer look (and getting the right libraries installed...), my original answer seems to be incorrect. The stack trace (which would ideally be included in your question :) ) points to the return line in Z itself. This is because your original code is trying to run a call to `sum` every time it iterates over `range(len(p))` rather than running it once on all the results.

You can adjust your code to do correctly return a single summed value by moving the sum *outside* the function, ie:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import poisson, norm

cs = 100
co = 300
mu = 4.7

G = poisson(mu)
p = G.pmf(np.arange(3*mu))

# Define Z(Q) function 

def Z(Q):
    for i in range(len(p)):
        yield p[i]*cs*max((Q-i), 0) + p[i]*co*max((i-Q), 0)

# Plot Q and (Q)

import pylab as pl

x = []
y = []

for Q in range(0, 12):
    x.append(Q)
    y.append(sum(Z(Q)))

pl.plot(x, y, '-o')
pl.show()
```

To summarise the changes:

- `Z(Q)` now yields each iteration of the function as described
- The `sum` operation is now run on the result of `Z(Q)`

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @tr00st  I tried to 'yield' it, while it has the same error message: In Z, Type error: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable.  And what do you mean by list(Z(Q) ? Sorry I am kind of new to Python

Comment: I just meant changing this:
y.append(Z(Q))
to this:
y.append(list(Z(Q)))

Though if you're getting the same error with the updated Z, that is unlikely to help. I've taken another look and will edit my answer shortly...

Comment: I tried that function, and it works! Thank you @tr00st      By the way, if I would like to output each (Q, sum(Z(Q)) into a csv file, it seems I cannot just add a sum() function before Z(Q) on my initial code. Or it will return the last (Q, Z(Q))

Comment: Not sure exactly what the problem with your code is, but I've added a CSV writer to the code, and dropped it here: https://pastebin.com/hTdkjHPH - worth comparing the two and seeing how the implementations differ

Comment: That's what I want. Thank you @tr00st